# How to process current and previous IoT Hub event from an azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

I have a simple scenario where I want to take the diff between current value of a parameter and previous value from IoT hub telemetry messages and attach this result and send to Time Series Insights environment (via an event hub if required so).

How can I achieve this? I am studying about Azure functions but not able to figure out how to exactly go about it.

The minimum timestamp difference between messages is 1 second and only edge devices (at max perhaps 3) will send the telemetry data. Each edge device might be collecting data from around 500 devices.

I am looking for a guidance on logical steps involved and a few critical pieces of Python code

Comment: you need to use Azure StreamAnalytics or store previous events somewhere

Comment: i specifically wanted to know how to do this using Azure functions. Something like setting cardinality to many, using durable functions etc.

Comment: if it can't be done easily with functions then I can consider stream analytics. However in either case I am looking for guidance/pointers on the steps involved and little pieces of code if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these telemetry messages or property changes? Also what's the scale (number of devices)? To do this effectively you need to ensure you have *both* the current and previous values, which means storing the last reported value and timestamp externally as it could be a long time between. The Event Hub is not guaranteed to have all past messages (default is 24h), so if there's a long lag between messages it's not the right store to rely on.

[Durable Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-entities?tabs=csharp) can be used to store state (using something similar to the Actor Model).  These are persisted in Azure Storage so at *extremely* high throughput a memory-only calculation option might make sense with delayed persistence, but you can build a memory-caching layer into your function to help if needed.  This is likely going to be the best bet for what you want to do.

For most people the performance hit of going to Azure storage and back is minimal and Durable Entities will be the easiest path forward.

Comment: Its telemetry data with min 1sec time difference. I have updated the question

Comment: Why not durable functions or normal functions with cardinality set to many?

Comment: Durable Entities are part of Durable Functions and can be called from regular Functions processing your data.  Keeping an entity with some state per device can be useful as it lets you store the pervious value indefinitely and gives you a mechanism for detecting duplicate messages or out-of-order messages that can happen in device disconnection scenarios.

Comment: I'm getting an error which I would like to track separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806712/out-of-proc-orchestrators-must-return-a-valid-json-schema-error-while-executin

Comment: But overall I feel this is the right approach for my current proof of concept so accepting this as answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it in a near-real time stream, the best solution is to use  Azsure Streaming Analytics using the LAG operator. ASA has a bunch of useful features that you will need such as the PARTITION BY and event ordering policies. Beware, ASA can be expensive to run and hard to work with, but is a good service for commercial solutions.

If you don't need near-real time, a plain 'ol python script that queries (blob) persisted data is a good option, and can be wrapped up in an Azure function if it doesn't take too long to run.

Azure functions are not recommended for stateful message processing. You simply have insufficient control of the number of function instances running, the size of the batch, etc. So it is impossible to consistently and confidently know what the 'previous' timeseries value is. With Azure functions, you have to develop assuming that concurrency is never going to be an issue, which you cannot do with streaming IoT data.

Comment: It will a soft real time system at best. Stream analytics will come into picture soon for slightly advanced analytics but for basic pipeline stuff like formula based KPI calculations I am thinking Azure functions would be sufficient

Comment: Not recommended. See edit in answer