# How do I send JSON to event hub from an azure function?

Tags: json, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am trying to process telemetry events from IoT hub, manipulate it a bit by adding/deleting a few JSON properties and send to event hub as described in a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755132/how-to-process-current-and-previous-iot-hub-event-from-an-azure-function). I am using durable entity functions to do the same as detailed in a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806712/out-of-proc-orchestrators-must-return-a-valid-json-schema-error-while-executin).

Overall goal is to store these in a Time Series Insights (TSI) environment and later represent it on some dashboards.

Let us say I calculate temperature in degree Fahrenheit using raw sensor data and put in a JSON message like below.

```
{
    "Timestamp" : "2021-06-10T00:00:00Z",
    "Parameters" : [
        {
            "Name" : "Temperature",
            "Value" : 89.06
        }
     ]
}
```

The "Name" and "Value" pair forms a JSON object (sorrounded by {}) and also is an element of JSON array "Parameters". I want to send this message to an event hub and in the event hub I want it to be received as is. So I modified the data type of output binding to binary/stream and setting the result as :

```
context.set_result(obj) 
#obj is a Python object corresponding to the JSON
```

Modified Output binding:

```
    {
      "type": "eventHub",
      "name": "$return",
      "direction": "out",
      "eventHubName": "myeventhub",
      "connection": "conn_eventhub",
      "dataType": "stream"
    }
```

However when I monitor the messages using Event hub explorer in VS code, I observe that the JSON has been converted to a string and wrapped in a bigger system-defined JSON like below.

```
{
  "entityExists": true,
  "entityState": "62.00009240670974",
  "results": [
    {
      "isError": false,
      "duration": 4,
      "result": "{\"Timestamp\": \"2021-06-10T00:00:00Z\", \"Parameters\": [{\"Name\": \"Temperature\", \"Value\": 89.06}]}"
    }
  ],
  "signals": []
}
```

But I don't want the JSON to be sent as a string. Instead I want it to be sent as a JSON object like below which is compatible with Time Series Insights.

```
{
  "entityExists": true,
  "entityState": "62.00009240670974",
  "results": [
    {
      "isError": false,
      "duration": 4,
      "result": {
          "Timestamp" : "2021-06-10T00:00:00Z",
          "Parameters" : [
              {
                "Name" : "Temperature",
                "Value" : 89.06
              }
          ]
       }
  ],
  "signals": []
}
```

How can it be done?

Comment: _"Instead I want it to be sent as a JSON object"_ - you can't. Or at least maybe not in the way you're expecting. - Please may you share a [mcve] of the code which sends the JSON?

Comment: The post has too much code already. Can you specify what detail you are looking for? Is it the expected output JSON format?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what a "JSON object" means in this context.  Can you share details about how you're reading events, what your bindings look like, and what the last snippet you shared represents?    At the end of the day, the body of an event is an opaque array of bytes to Event Hubs, it does not transform or inspect it.   The format that you're seeing is most likely an artifact of how the event is being read and interpreted.

Comment: I have updated the question with more explanation. Hope this clarifies the intent.

Comment: It's not the intent I have confusion about, it's how you're sending the JSON. Remember JavaScript sends JSON as a string (that's what JSON is).

Comment: Ok by the way the code is in Python. I tried sending as string in set_result with data_type in binding also set to string, the difference in the result is that characters like backslash and quotes are escaped twice like this - "result": "\"{\\\"Timestamp\\\": \\\"2021-06-10T00:00:00Z\\\", \\\"Parameters\\\": [{\\\"Name\\\": \\\"Temperature\\\", \\\"Value\\\": 89.06}]}\"". I also tried sending Python object with binding data_type set to binary but result is same as for stream type

Comment: From this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/digital-twins/how-to-integrate-time-series-insights) it looks like it is possible to send a Time Series Insights compatible JSON

Comment: We still don't know what you meant by "JSON object", how you're reading events, or what your bindings look like - those are pretty important details to answer your question.     Since we don't know the details, the best that I can offer is to comment on the general flow.  Since an event body is ultimately just a byte array, typically there's a serializer that runs as part of the Function context which translates any language-native object into either bytes or a string.  The bindings will either use the bytes verbatim or encode the string as a UTF-8 byte array.

Comment: Thanks for answer. By JSON object I mean the set of JSON key/value pairs sorrounded by {} as described [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp).

The details of binding is in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806712/out-of-proc-orchestrators-must-return-a-valid-json-schema-error-while-executin) I mentioned in the beginning.

Comment: I think that I understand the disconnect; the notion of "JSON object" that you've linked to is a JavaScript construct and differs from the common use.   [JSON](https://www.json.org/) is a text-based data interchange format.  The object representation for this would differ depending on the language consuming it.  Where Event Hubs is concerned, to share JSON, it would need to be represented as a byte encoded version of the text.   The double-escape that you're seeing indicates that something is double-encoding when serializing.

Comment: So since I am using Python should I just convert the str output to bytes[] using and then call return result? I mean something like: 
`finaljson = json.dumps(pythonobj)`
`context.set_result(finaljson.encode('utf-8'))`
instead of simply `context.set_result(pythonobj)`

Comment: I lack the proper insight into how the bridge between Python and the bindings works to answer that.  The binding itself (which is written in C#) is happy to accept a string or byte array or `EventData` instance.  The [Python docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-output?tabs=python) aren't so clear.   Your best bet is likely to test how that translates for a downstream consumer.